# Solving $\int\frac{\ln(x \ln(x))}{x} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to solve $\int\frac{\ln(x \ln(x))}{x} dx$?

My work:
Let $t = \ln(x) \implies x=  e^t ; dt = \dfrac{dx}{x}$

So above integral changes to,
$$\int t ( e^t t) dt$$
$$\int t^2 e^t dt$$

Using IBP to get:
$$t^2e^t - 2te^t + 2e^t + C$$

Undoing the substitution to get,
$$x\log^2(x) - 2x\log(x) + 2x + C$$

But differentiating this doesn't give the original integral. I've definitely done anything wrong which I'm unable to understand. Can anyone help me to solve it?

Also I'm wondering if We could solve it without using by parts.

---

**Edit**
I tried again as suggested in comments.
$$\int\dfrac{\log(x \log(x))}{x}dx \overset{t\to\log(x)}= \int\log(e^t t) dt = \int t + \log(t)  = \dfrac{t^2}{2} + t\log(t) - t + C$$

By undoing the substitution,
$$\boxed{\dfrac{\log^2(x)}{2} + \log(x)\log(\log x) - \log(x)+ C}$$

What's wrong with this?

Comment: It's $\ln(x \ln x)$ and not $\ln x (x \ln x)$. Seems like this is what you did wrong

Comment: Integrate $\ln{(te^t)}dt$

Answer (score 1):

We make the substitution $t = \ln| x | $ or $x = e^t$.

Then $dt = {1 \over x} dx$ or ${dx \over x} = dt$.

Thus, the given integral can be simplified as
$$
I = \int \ln| t e^t | dt
$$

Using the formula of integration by parts
$$
\int u dv = u v -  \int v du,
$$
we can simplify the integral $I$ as
$$
I = t \ln| t e^t | - \int \ t d\left[ \ln\left( t e^t \right) \right]
$$

A simple calculation shows that
$$
I = t \ln | t e^t | - \int \ t {1 \over t e^t} \ \left( e^t + t e^t \right) 
 dt
$$

Simplifying, we get
$$
I = t \ln | t e^t | - \int \ (t + 1) dt = t \ln | t e^t | - {t^2 \over 2} - t + c
$$
where $c$ is an integration constant.

Back-substitution of $t = \ln| x |$ yields the final result as
$$
I = \ln| x | \ln\left| x \ln | x | \right| - {(\ln| x |)^2 \over 2} - \ln| x | + c
$$

Comment: Can you please also check my method which I added after an edit?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
I&= \int \ln (x \ln x) d(\ln x) \\
=& \ln x \cdot \ln (x \ln x)-\int \ln x \cdot \frac{1}{x \ln x}\left(x \cdot \frac{1}{x}+\ln x\right) d x \\
=& \ln x \cdot\ln (x \ln x)-\int \frac{1+\ln x}{x} d x \\
=& \ln x \cdot\ln (x \ln x)-\int(1+\ln x) d(\ln x) \\
=& \ln x \cdot \ln (x \ln x)-\ln x-\frac{\ln ^{2} x}{2}+C .
\end{aligned}
$$